# Auto drop to frame , debug mode ,eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ide

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java
Maven Projects
when I'm on debug mode and try to
edit the code and save it, the green
line should go to the first line of the
function (like drop to frame) to see
the change, my problem now when I
edit the code and save it, the green
line do not go back to first line of
the function as before

what settings should I modify?